# Accessing \\. as an {UUID}

Tags: windows

Windows has this feature(? maybe undocumented) where you can make a new folder named `{UUID}` and it does something special depending on the UUID.

I only know how to use `{UUID}` to add control panel (and a few similar things) to Desktop/arbitrary folders, but I'd like to add an alias to `\\.` instead. I don't know its UUID (or if it even has one), tho. Does anyone know the UUID for this very specific thing? This is impossible to search anywhere because search engines don't like symbols.

Comment: @davidpostill This question is not soliciting any recommendations, this is incorrectly put on hold.

Comment: What you're referring to is Windows Shell specific behavior when folders are encountered in the format you suggested (i.e. MyFolder.{Extension CLSID}). What are you trying to achieve with "an alias to \\."?

Comment: I thought by making an {UUID} that represents \\. I could get access to \\. and raw disks from WSL (for use with dd)

Comment: This is not supported. See: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/689 Alternatively, to write to a disk, you can use Rufus, Win32DiskImager, or even the Win32 port of dd.

Comment: I didn't ask if it was supported, I asked if it could work. I do unsupported things all the time.

Comment: I agree. That wasn't clear. By not supported, I meant it won't work at all. The linked GitHub issue has the details.

Comment: The issue only talks about `/dev/*` mappings for raw devices. It doesn't talk about working around their lack by using `\\.`